# Facebook Messenger: How do I get back to the greeting text?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I added the Facebook Messenger chat bot to my website. I added a greeting and everything is working fine.

Then I tested the chat by typing a chat in it.

Now I am unable to get back to it showing the greeting text. I deleted the conversation on messenger, but now it is just showing a blank chat bot on my website.

How do I get back to the normal greeting?

Comment: The greeting is only supposed to be shown when the user interacts with your bot for the first time … After they have initiated a conversation, it won’t be shown any more.

Answer (score 0):

Open your web page in incognito mode (cmd+shift+n - for chrome on Mac). Click on the Facebook Messenger Web Chat, login to the Facebook and you should have a fresh chat with greeting as well.